# Batch file I made to keep track of archery scores keeps crashing after entering 3 scores

Tags: batch-file

```
:inputScores (
    if %arrowInputCount% gtr %totalNumOfArrows% (

        goto output

    )
    if %updateCount% == true (

        set /a arrowInputCount+=1

    ) else (

        set updateCount=true

    )
    cls
    echo Input the score for arrow %arrowInputCount%^/%totalNumOfArrows%
    echo Score range: 1-%bullseyeWorth%
    echo Input 'x' for an X
    echo Input 'm' for a miss
    set /p tempScore=Input: 

    :testScore (

        if %tempScore% == x (

            rem user entered x

            if %scoreString% == null (

                set scoreString=%tempScore%
                set /a totalScore+=%bullseyeWorth%
                goto inputScores

            ) else (

                set scoreString=%scoreString%^,%tempScore%
                set /a totalScore+=%bullseyeWorth%
                goto inputScores

            )

        ) else if %tempScore% == m (

            rem user entered m

            if %scoreString% == null (

                set scoreString=%tempScore%
                goto inputScores

            ) else (

                set scoreString=%scoreString%^,%tempScore%
                goto inputScores

            )

        ) else (

            if %tempScore% gtr 0 if %tempScore% leq %bullseyeWorth% (

                rem this will handle if the user enters a number
                echo stub
                pause
                exit

            ) else (

                rem user didn't enter a valid number
                echo -
                echo Invalid Input
                pause
                set updateCount=false
                goto inputScores

            )

        )

    )

)

:output (

    rem program outputs the data

    cls
    echo stub
    pause
    exit

)
```

This is the offending fragment of the code for my program that is supposed to take in archery scores and output a file tat contains all the scores along with other data such as score % out of total possible score.

For the purposes of this fragment working, assume that these variables have already been set to these values:

```
arrowInputCount=0
totalNumOfArrows=9
updateCount=0
bullseyeWorth=5
scoreString=null
```

When I run the file it works fine up until I enter the third score at which point it crashes. I have done a desk check of the whole thing and I can't see why it would work fine for the first 2 scores entered and then crash once I enter the third one. I haven't written code to handle when the user enters a number yet so in my testing I was only entering 'x' and 'm'. I have tried entering the first 3 scores as all x's, all m's and a combination of x's and m's. In all cases it crashes after entering the third score.

Answer (score 0):

One of the if statements was causing the crash because of the commas in scoreString. I enclosed the reference to scoreString with "" and it works now.